# How to export csv down instead of across

Tags: powershell

I have a function that simply pulls the SPF, DKIM and DMARC records to a file and the console.

```
Name          : Domain.com
SpfRecord     : v=spf1 ip4:?.1?.??.153 include: <Etc?>
SpfAdvisory   : An SPF-record
DmarcRecord   : v=DMARC1; 
DmarcAdvisory : Domain has a valid DMARC record.
DkimRecord    : <Etc>
DkimSelector  : <Etc>
DkimAdvisory  : <Etc>
```

When I `$InvokeReturnValues | Export-Csv 'C:\Reports\SPFetc.csv' -NoTypeInformation`
The information exports across the csv left to right in columns.
How can I change that so the information exports like above?

Comment: Then it wouldn't be a CSV. What do you actually want? :-)

Comment: I was kind of hoping for it to be readable like the screen output above. At the end of the day I am exporting it to a file, comparing if  for changes since my 'master' file was created.
I am open to ideas @MathiasR.Jessen

Comment: I find the output pleasing as is. Putting it in columns seems less efficient for readability.

Comment: The big question is: do you want to compare them _by hand_, or _by automation_? Outputting the list view as-is to file is fine if you want to do it manually, but if you have many changes you might want to do it programmatically, at which point you'll have to make a tradeoff between human readability and machine readability :-)

Comment: I was thinking one file would be human readable and one file would be for compare. I suppose this is why I got down voted since it reduces automation. @MathiasR.Jessen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't actually *want* a CSV file, **don't use `Export-Csv`**.

`Out-File` or `Set-Content` will do just fine:

```
$InvokeReturnValues |Format-List |Out-File
```

Depending on the input data type, `Format-List` may not be explicitly necessary - in this case where you have an array of custom objects with more than 4 properties, PowerShell will automatically format it using the List view anyway.

---

If you're considering use of the data for further automation - an automatic diff of two versions of the data for example - you might want to stick with CSV.

You can always re-create the list view in your console by simply importing the data again:

```
$oldData = Import-Csv path\to\SPFetc.csv
$oldData |Format-List
```